# Understanding max output voltage of a solar cell data sheet

Tags: solar-cell

For the following solar cell datasheet values, what would be the max output voltage of the solar cell?

Would it be the open circuit voltage typical or the max operating one? What exactly is the open circuit voltage?

Referenced from [AM-8701 Datasheet(PDF) - Sanyo Semicon Device (alldatasheet.com)](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/251229/SANYO/AM-8701.html)

[image]

Comment: Note: Solar cell/panel has internal resistance, so max voltage is only achieved when there is no current flow. No current means no power. Max current is achieved when you short it out, but then there's no voltage at the "load," so again, no useful power is generated. Somewhere in between, a little bit (not a lot) less than max voltage, and a little bit (not a lot) less than max current is the _maximum power point_ (MPP). That's the operating point where the most power is delivered to the load. Max voltage, max current, and MPP all shift when the amount of illumination on the panel changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be the open circuit voltage typical or the max operating one?

Open circuit voltage is the voltage the solar cell will output at the conditions provided.

The table you have there shows that the Open circuit voltage is 6V typ. (on average) at a luminance of 50,000 Lx ([Lux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux))

There may be a graph on that datasheet that provides the change in voltage in relation to the change in light intensity.

> What exactly is the open circuit voltage

Open circuit voltage is the voltage between the terminals of your solar cell with **no load attached**.

Short circuit current is the current through a wire when the two terminals are shorted. A shorted connection ideally has a voltage of zero, while an open connection ideally has a current of zero.

> what would be the max output voltage of the solar cell

The voltage will depend on the luminance on the area of the photovoltaics inside and maximum output voltage will depend on temperature (colder environments increase the maximum voltage) of the solar cell. There is no maximum listed in the table you provided.

The Maximum Output section on the table provided shows your maximum wattage at a specific luminance. With solar cells, there is no "maximum" per say, it comes down to how many photons you can get to hit the photovoltaics inside.

It is best to take some measurements in the primary environment your project will be in and work with those values.

**To further read this table, some key definitions:**

- AM-1.5 is your Air Mass rating ([wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_mass_(solar_energy)), scroll down some)
- 100mW/cm^2 is your intensity ([wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics)))

*All measurements given on a datasheet will have a specific condition they were measured under. You can expect different values if measured under different conditions.*

---

Update: Look at Figure 1 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.egypro.2013.07.084) (doi 10.1016). It has information on the relationship between illumination intensity, short circuit current, and open circuit voltage. In the paper you will see that short circuit voltage increases logarithmically, while short circuit current increases linearly. It's an interesting relationship to say the least!

*Note: for future questions include sources for images such as the datasheet to help us answer your questions on the EE.SE.*

Comment: Max output voltage is temperature dependent. Colder->higher voltage.

Comment: @JohnDoty Edited. Thank you for the clarification on that!

Comment: Datasheet reference added. So to be sure - this is the typical value at 50,000 Lux, but realistically the lux from sunlight could go up to 100,000 and therefore the open voltage and corresponding max voltage will increase as well past 6V and 4.6V respectively? @Pxl

Comment: @starboy Correct, yes (though maybe not linear increase). I would suggest you take your solar cell to the environment you plan on configuring your system and measuring the output at peak light levels. This will give you your theoretical "maximum" you can expect to see in the environment you set up in.

Comment: Interesting! Is there anyway to find these values computationally rather than out in the field? It would be useful to know what max voltage output is achieved at say 100,000 lux.

Comment: @Pxl thank you very much for your help - may I ask how you figured out it was 50,000lux? Very new to reading these types of datasheets.

Comment: @starboy No problem. As for the source of the 50k Lx, when looking at a datasheet, you will see a table set up usually with columns as follows: *Parameter, symbol, conditions, min/typ/max, unit*.
I acquired the condition of 50,000 lux (SS 50kLx) from the conditions column.

Comment: @Pxl The voltage is far from linear, approximately logarithmic. Doubling the illumination only increases the voltage by a few percent.

Comment: @JohnDoty Correct, yes. Thank you for the additional clarification!

Comment: @JohnDoty any reference to this information regarding the relationship between voltage and illumination being logarithmic?

Comment: @starboy Look at Figure 1 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.egypro.2013.07.084) (doi; 10.1016). It has information on the relationship between illumination intensity, short circuit current, and open circuit voltage.

In the paper you will see that open circuit voltage increases logarithmically, while short circuit current increases linearly. It's an interesting relationship to say the least!